# Order By - Deixar registro específico por primeiro

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, classificação, query

```
Store_Name  | Sales | Date
America     | 1500  | 05-Jan-1999
Boston      | 700   | 08-Jan-1999
Canada      | 300   | 08-Jan-1999
Dinamarca   | 250   | 07-Jan-1999
```

Tenho essa tabela, gostaria de ordenar de uma forma onde **Boston** fosse o primeiro registro, a ordem dos demais sendo irrelevante. Como faço?

Comment: Qual a necessidade disso?

Comment: atender a demanda do cliente

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não é necessário usar `case`

```
select *
from t
order by store_name != 'Boston'
```

O falso ordena antes do verdadeiro. E pode fazer uma ordenação normal com as outras linhas:

```
order by store_name != 'Boston', store_name
```

Comment: Esta é bem melhor que a aceita.

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from tabela
order by case when store_name = 'Boston' then 1 else 2 end;
```

Comment: Tenho curiosidade em entender o que esse `1 else 2` faz. No meu entendimento significa _"ordene pela coluna `Store_Name` (ou seja, coluna 1) quando esta for `'Boston'` ou então pela coluna `Sales` (coluna 2) caso contrário_. Estou enganado?

Comment: @Piovezan Na verdade, esta SQL quer dizer: 'Crie um campo anônimo, cujo valor é 1 caso store_name seja Boston, e 2 para qualquer outro caso - e ordene meu resultado por este campo.'

Comment: @OnoSendai, boa explicação.

Comment: @Piovezan, **Não!** Veja este fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/746fe/2

Comment: @OnoSendai Obrigado pela explicação :)

Comment: @jean Obrigado pelo exemplo :)

Answer (score 1):

Eu prefiro uma alternativa em que eu não precise criar um order by dinâmico

```
select Store_Name, Sales, Date, case when store_name = 'Boston' then 0 else 9 end as Orderby
from tabela
order by orderby
```

além desta alternativa você pode adicionar uma coluna orderby na tabela, dai fica fácil colocar mais de um registro com uma ordenação "fixa".

Acredito que a solução usando um case na cláusula order by pode gerar query plans não muito "legais" (isso precisa ser testado antes claro!)

Aqui um [**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/746fe/3) para referência

Comment: Fiz um teste agora num ambiente Oracle e o Plano foi igual (tendo order by) , só mudou quando sem o order by.

Comment: Não entendi quando você disse 'pode gerar query plans não muito "legais"', poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Quis dizer que pode (e isso precisa ser testado) fazer com que engine escolha uma execução mais lenta, afetando performance