# Ordernar um Select por critério fora do banco de dados

Tags: mysql, select, sql-select

Gostaria de criar um `SELECT` com a relação de pessoal aqui da minha empresa.

```
SELECT função, nome FROM responsavel;
```

Até aí tudo bem. Mas como ordenar do Gerente, passando pelo Encarregado, Supervisor até Auxiliar de serviços gerais, nesta ordem?

OU SEJA:

```
GERENTE, FULANO;
ENCARREGADO, CICLANO;
SUPERVISOR, BETÂNIO;
AUX. DE SERV. GERAIS, REGÂNIO;
```

Nesta ordem.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Order By - Deixar registro específico por primeiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26301/order-by-deixar-registro-espec%c3%adfico-por-primeiro)

Comment: @RobertodeCampos, não acho que seja uma duplicata viu, parece o que ele quer é algo como uma Ordenação de acordo com uma hierarquia da empresa, como se, o "Gerente" fosse mais importante e viesse primeiro, depois "Encarregado". Já no outro caso do link, o cara queria que só a cidade "Boston" ficasse em primeiro.
Pelo menos é o que eu entendi, e se ele fosse usar a mesma ideia da resposta do link, acho que teria que fazer `!=`pra todo mundo, ficaria estranho. Mas isso é o que eu acho kkk

Comment: Editei a minha resposta, acredito que agora esta de acordo :)

Comment: Tem razão @RichardWillian, vou tirar meu voto como duplicada.

Answer (score 5):

Olha esta solução com case:

```
SELECT funcao  nome FROM responsavel
    order by case funcao 
                when "GERENTE" THEN 1
                when "ENCARREGADO" THEN 2
                when "SUPERVISOR" THEN 3
                when "AUX. DE SERV." THEN 4 
                else  99999
            end;
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34358/4927

Comment: no caso dele não precisaria, pois ele queria apenas que um dos campos viesse por primeiro, no seu você quer passar a ordem dos valores.

Comment: obrigado @MarcianoMachado! Me ajudou muito

Comment: Tem razão @MarcianoMachado, já dei meu +1

Answer (score 1):

Talvez a melhor forma de resolver seu problema seria acrescentar uma nova coluna como uma de `Importância Cargo`ou `Hierarquia Ofício`, o nome não importa tanto, mas sim a aplicação.

Adicionando essa nova coluna, você poderia fazer um simples `ORDER BY`, fazendo com que sua `Query`fique mais limpa.

```
       FUNCAO       |        NOME      | HIERARQUIA_OFICIO|
GERENTE             | FULANO           |        1         |
ENCARREGADO SETOR 1 | CICLANO DA MATA  |        2         |
ENCARREGADO SETOR 2 | CICLANO DA SILVA |        2         |
SUPERVISOR          | BETÂNIO          |        3         |
AUX. DE SERV. GERAIS| REGÂNIO          |        4         |

SELECT FUNCAO, NOME FROM RESPONSAVEL
ORDER BY HIERARQUIA_OFICIO;
```

Claro, não sei o quanto vai ser complicado de adicionar uma nova coluna, as vezes é necessário mudar **MUITA** coisa no seu sistema, ai realmente não compensa. Mas se der, talvez essa seja a melhor forma.